# Subsequent Call to Actor Freezes Program

Tags: sockets, scala, actor

I put together the code below; the intent was to have a *non*-blocking server accept a connection and then pass off this connection to an actor for further processing. This works the first time through, but on the subsequent request the program freezes at `conServ ! servSoc.accept`. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
import java.net._
import java.io._

import java.nio._
import java.nio.channels._

import java.util._

import scala.actors.Actor
import scala.actors.Actor._

def test() = {  
    var channel: ServerSocketChannel = null
    val isa: InetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(23)

    val conServ = actor { 
        react {
            case conn: Socket => {                              
                                try {
                                    var pw: PrintWriter = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), true)
                                    pw.println("Current time: " + new Date)
                                    pw.close
                                    conn.close
                                } catch {
                                    case ioe: IOException => println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage)
                                    case e: Exception => println("Exception: " + e.getMessage)
                                }                               
                            }
        }
    }

    try {
        channel = ServerSocketChannel.open
        channel.configureBlocking(false)
        channel.socket().bind(isa)
        var selector: Selector = Selector.open
        channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT)
        println("** Server ready for requests **")

        while (true) {
            if (selector.select > 0) {
                var selKeys: Set[SelectionKey] = selector.selectedKeys
                var selIt: Iterator[SelectionKey] = selKeys.iterator
                while (selIt.hasNext) {
                    var key: SelectionKey = selIt.next.asInstanceOf[SelectionKey]
                    selIt.remove
                    if (key.isAcceptable) {
                        var ssc: ServerSocketChannel = key.channel.asInstanceOf[ServerSocketChannel]
                        var servSoc: ServerSocket = ssc.socket
                        try {
                            conServ ! servSoc.accept
                        } catch {
                            case ioe: IOException => println(ioe.printStackTrace)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                continue
            }
        }

    } catch {
        case ioe: IOException => println("Could not listen to port 23. " + ioe.printStackTrace)
        case e: Exception => println("Error: " + e.printStackTrace)
    }
}

test
```

Answer (score 3):

Enclose your `react` in a `loop` block like this:

```
val conServ = actor { 
  loop {
    react {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

What happens now, is that your actor is started, processes the first message and is not "reacting" again to process additional message from its queue.

See [*An actor's act method that uses loop*](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/actors-and-concurrency.html#lst%3aact-with-loop).

Answer (score 2):

This is what an actor do, treating one message at the time. What you want is a separate thread to handle each request. For this you can try using Futures.

Comment: I was under the impression that `futures` are placeholders for yet to be determined values and not new thread generating objects like the `spawn` method. Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: well actually both Futures.future { ... } starts a asynchronous task that will eventually set the result on the returned future object.